# Call center Calculating monthly and annual percentage

Tags: join, aggregate-functions, percentage, cognos

I'm trying to put together management information for a call center.

I've got the following info on every call that gets logged:
[CreatedOn] = Date & time of creation
[Case_status_name] = Reason for closing the call (Answered by 1st line, transferred to 2nd, call back request etc.)

Now what I'm looking to make is a graph which will show in one line the % of calls that were answered by the 1st line and the annual average% of calls closed by the first line during the last 12 months.

I can get the months from [CreatedOn] with the extract function, the same goes for the year.
I can group the [Case_status_name] in 1st line answered and everything else with a simple if statement.
But I'm having trouble getting the percentages right for both the month and the year together.

I can get sensible data if I only calculate the yearly average or if I calcluate the monthly average. But when I try to do them together, I wind up getting all kinds of crazy values.

What is a proper way to get the monthly and annual percentage in the same table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create Query
2. Add Column [Month] with expression

   ```
   _first_of_month([CreatedOn])
   ```
3. Add Query Item [Total] with expression

   ```
   1
   ```
4. Add Query Item [Answered by 1st line] with expression

   ```
   case when [Case_status_name] = 'Answered by 1st line' then 1 else 0 end
   ```
5. Add Query Item [closed by the first line] with expression

   ```
   case when [Case_status_name] = 'closed by the first line' then 1 else 0 end
   ```
6. Filter this Query

   ```
   [CreatedOn] between _first_of_month(_add_months(current_date;-12))
                   and _last_of_month(_add_months(current_date;-1))
   ```
7. Add Query Item [% of calls answered by the 1st line] with expression

   ```
   [Answered by 1st line] / [Total]
   ```
8. Add Query Item [12-month average] with expression

   ```
   sum([closed by the first line] for report) / sum([Total] for report)
   ```
9. Build Graph based on this Query

Comment: Yes! Thank you!
It took a little finagling, but I'm getting the results I was after!